# Only using Stream dispose and ZipArchive not dispose, can the resources be cleaned correctly?

Tags: .net

I have a class, that doesn't handle/dispose it manually :

```
public class ZipReader
{
    private ZipArchive _zip;
    public ZipReader(Stream stream)
    {
        _zip= new ZipArchive(stream);
    }
    
    public string GetXmlContent(Stream stream, string path)
    {
        var c = _zip.Entries.Single(_ => _.FullName.Contains(path));
        using (var s = c.Open())
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

I want user to handle/dispose it on external code by themselves, like :

```
    var path = @"D:\git\MiniExcel\samples\xlsx\TestMultiSheet.xlsx";
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        var reader = new ZipReader(stream);
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetXmlContent(stream,"xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml"));
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetXmlContent(stream,"xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml"));
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetXmlContent(stream,"xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml"));
    }
```

Can the resources be cleaned correctly after only dispose FileStream?

---

I've tried below code to run 10000 times and it looks like GC clean the resources very well, and no obvious difference.

```
void Main()
{
    Test1();
    Test2();
}

void Test2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("==== using ZipArchive dispose ====");
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var path = @"D:\git\MiniExcel\samples\xlsx\TestMultiSheet.xlsx";


    Console.WriteLine("start memory usage: " + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / (1024 * 1024) + $"MB & run time : {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive(stream))
        {
            var reader = new ReaderWithZipArchiveDispose();
            reader.GetXmlContent(zip, "xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml").ToList();
            reader.GetXmlContent(zip, "xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml").ToList();
            reader.GetXmlContent(zip, "xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml").ToList();

            if (i % 5000 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine($"no.{i} memory usage: " + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / (1024 * 1024) + $"MB & run time : {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("end memory usage: " + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / (1024 * 1024) + $"MB & run time : {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
}

void Test1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("==== wihout using ZipArchive dispose ====");
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var path = @"D:\git\MiniExcel\samples\xlsx\TestMultiSheet.xlsx";


    Console.WriteLine("start memory usage: " + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / (1024 * 1024) + $"MB & run time : {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            var reader = new ReaderWithoutZipArchiveDispose(stream);
            reader.GetXmlContent(stream, "xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml").ToList();
            reader.GetXmlContent(stream, "xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml").ToList();
            reader.GetXmlContent(stream, "xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml").ToList();

            if (i % 5000 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine($"no.{i} memory usage: " + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / (1024 * 1024) + $"MB & run time : {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("end memory usage: " + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / (1024 * 1024) + $"MB & run time : {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public class ReaderWithoutZipArchiveDispose
{
    private ZipArchive _zip;
    public ReaderWithoutZipArchiveDispose(Stream stream)
    {
        _zip = new ZipArchive(stream);
    }

    public string GetXmlContent(Stream stream, string path)
    {
        var c = _zip.Entries.Single(_ => _.FullName.Contains(path));
        using (var s = c.Open())
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

public class ReaderWithZipArchiveDispose
{
    public string GetXmlContent(ZipArchive _zip, string path)
    {
        var c = _zip.Entries.Single(_ => _.FullName.Contains(path));
        using (var s = c.Open())
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

==== wihout using ZipArchive dispose ====
start memory usage: 51MB & run time : 3ms
no.0 memory usage: 51MB & run time : 8ms
no.5000 memory usage: 51MB & run time : 1304ms
end memory usage: 51MB & run time : 2561ms
==== using ZipArchive dispose ====
start memory usage: 51MB & run time : 3ms
no.0 memory usage: 51MB & run time : 8ms
no.5000 memory usage: 51MB & run time : 1271ms
end memory usage: 51MB & run time : 2492ms
```

Answer (score -2):

All variable declared in the using statement will be cleared when the using ends. So the object ZipReader will be deleted in the same time than the FileStream, and by extension the ZipArchive also.

To check, you can try to call the ZipReader object after and the compiler will stop you.